# IPV6: Linux-Clients does not register Hostnames via DDNS

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, ddns

I have a problem to get Hostnames registered in DNS (Windows AD DNS-Server) when they request a IPV6 (NA). While IPV4 gets fine i can see in syslog an "added reverse and added forward mapping" it doesnt get shown for ipv6 linux clients but Windows clients does via the dhcp server (shown in syslog).

i have the following config:

**dhclient6.conf**

```
   interface "eth0" {
   send fqdn.fqdn "debtemp.ad.example.com.";
   send fqdn.encoded on;
   send fqdn.server-update off;
}
```

**dhcpd6.conf**

```
default-lease-time 2592000;
preferred-lifetime 604800;
option dhcp-renewal-time 3600;
option dhcp-rebinding-time 7200;

allow leasequery;
ddns-dual-stack-mixed-mode true;
update-conflict-detection true;
ddns-guard-id-must-match true;
ddns-other-guard-is-dynamic true;
ddns-update-style standard;
ddns-updates on;
ddns-domainname "example.com.";
ddns-rev-domainname "ip6.arpa.";
option dhcp6.domain-search "example.com.";
option dhcp6.info-refresh-time 21600;
get-lease-hostnames true;
authoritative;
```

...